# Can Azure Pipelines compare executed number of tests across different runs?

Tags: testing, azure-pipelines, test-coverage

We have X tests in our repo, being executed in Azure Pipelines. Recently we made a change which partially broke test discovery, hence for a while there were only (X - Y) tests running (successfully). So all the runs were successful but the number of tests dramatically decreased and we were just lucky to notice this accidentally after a week of broken behavior.

Is there an easy measure of preventing this in ADO pipelines? We use .NET, so either related or not related to it. I imagine something like comparing the number of tests executed and firing warnings if there is a significant decrease of their amount.

Answer (score 0):

> I imagine something like comparing the number of tests executed and firing warnings if there is a significant decrease of their amount.

Since you are use .Net, you can try to set the field: **minimumExpectedTests**  in Visual Studio Test task.

For example：

```
- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'VsTest - testAssemblies'
  inputs:
    testAssemblyVer2: |
     **\*test*.dll
     !**\*TestAdapter.dll
     !**\obj\**
    searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    resultsFolder: '$(Agent.TempDirectory)\TestResults'
    failOnMinTestsNotRun: true
    minimumExpectedTests: numberX
```

You can set an expected number of tests. It will run successfully when the number of tests is greater than or equal to. If the expectation is not met, it will report an error.

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [Visual Studio test task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/vstest?view=azure-devops)